# update-database ef6 "Unable to create an object of type 'CMSDBContext'"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="2.5.43" />
</ItemGroup>
```

```
public class CMSDBContext : DbContext
{
    public CMSDBContext(DbContextOptions<CMSDBContext> options)
                : base(options)
    {
    }

    // Dbsets
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        CustomDateConverter.DateToUTC(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        foreach (var auditableEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditable>())
        {
            if (auditableEntity.State == EntityState.Added || auditableEntity.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                switch (auditableEntity.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        auditableEntity.Entity.CreatedAt = currentDateTime;
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        auditableEntity.Entity.UpdatedAt = currentDateTime;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Registering services:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddPresistenceInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<CMSDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(SettingManager.CMSConnectionString));

    #region Repositories
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IReadonlyRepository<>), typeof(ReadonlyRepository<>));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(ISectionRepository), typeof(SectionRepository));
    #endregion

    #region Cache
    var redisConfigSection = SettingManager.GetSection(RedisSettings.SectionName);

    services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(sp => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(new ConfigurationOptions
            {
                EndPoints = { $"{redisConfigSection["Server"]}:{redisConfigSection["Port"]}" },
                AllowAdmin = true,
                AbortOnConnectFail = false,
            }));

    services.AddSingleton<ICacheService, RedisCacheService>();
    #endregion

    return services;
}
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
"CMSConnection": "Server=Sandy-NB\\LOCALSERVER;Database=cms_db;User Id=sa;Password=xxxx;"
```

```
PM> Update-database --verbose
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create an object of type 'CMSDBContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

There were solutions about making the project as startup project (already done and no success)

I tried to initially create an empty database with the database name and tried again -- no success

Pretty sure that the code has no issues because it was working previously on other machines but what would be the possible issue causing this problem?

I installed Entity Framework Core, Entity Framework Core SQL Server, Entity Framework Tools for the application layer and infrastructure layer version 6.0.1

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="2.5.43" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Core\CMS.Application\CMS.Application.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Core\CMS.Domain\CMS.Domain.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Shared\CMS.Shared.Common\CMS.Common.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer was actually in the question, there were two different projects , the persistance layer Project and web api layer Project and of course the startup project should be the program.cs.

Comment: Welcome to SO Sandy. You can mark your own answer as the solution. Remember to upvote other answers if they were helpful. :)

Comment: the api project should be selected as host browsing , while in the package manager console make sure the persistance project is selected

Answer (score 0):

The error shows if the EF tools cannot determine how to build your `DbContext` (as stated by the error).

The docs for the command you find actually state `-v` or `--verbose` as command argument to show verbose output. The latter, `--verbose`, only works if you invoke the command from something like PowerShell. If you run from inside VisualStudio's PM Console, the correct argument is actually `-verbose` or `-v` and not `--verbose` (note the difference in dashes).

When using `-verbose`, it should tell you which project it finds and uses to initialize your `DbContext`.

Remember, since your `CMBSContext` has no parameterless constructor, the tool must know how to resolve the context's dependencies, and thus, the project it finds must build a host, where the host has configured all the necessary dependencies (as stated in the link description from the error output).

In case it resolves the wrong project I recommend using the EF tools from PowerShell instead (or whatever terminal you like), and then run something like the following:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
dotnet ef database update -v -s <absolute-path-to-project-that-knows-how-to-configure-your-dbcontexts-dependencies>
```

I don't know if you can do something similar from the Visual Studio's PM Console. Maybe if you look in the docs you can find it.

If you still cannot make it work try to remove the constructor with parameters, and override `OnConfigure` (if you need any configuration, that is). Then the tools don't need to be able to resolve your context's dependencies, and will just new it up with the parameterless constructor.